# How to model mechanical systems that change configuration over time?

Tags: mass, spring, oscillators

If I have some simple mechanical system, say - a mass attached to one end of a spring fixed at the other end, I can write differential equations describing such systems which can also be handled analytically.

But what if I let the system be for example a mass "jumping" on top of a spring? As far as I can see, the system will have to states: one in which the mass is in contact with the spring and one in which the mass is "flying" above the spring while the spring can oscillate freely. How do I "connect" the equations of these different states? Are they generally possible to handle analytically or is numerical simulation necessary?

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on how the mass is added to the spring, i.e., you could write for the mass attached to the spring as $M(t)$. Here $M(t)=m_1 + m_2 f(t)$ where $f(t)$ is some function of time. In principle, you would have to find a realistic $f(t)$ based on the dynamical process of how the mass is added, but you could just assume a reasonable function. Obtaining analytical solutions will depend on which function $f(t)$ is assumed.

Comment: Also you can do a lot using non-homogeneous solutions, e.g. differential equations that do not equate to zero. Using this you can add additional forces, which can reprsent many things. See something like this http://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/En4/Notes/vibrations_forced/vibrations_forced.htm ,I think you can solve cases similar like the one you mention in this way. If this is possible in an analytical manner is completely dependent on the case.